# Apache: Loading external resources

Tags: apache-2.4, configuration, tomcat, httpd, resources

I have two Tomcats on two different servers (machines) working in the same network deploying the same application. The application has a .xml descryptor that loads external folder with configs, images, project properties, icons etc. When I load the app in my browser on the machines where I have my Tomcat, the app works and it loads the external folder. But when I load my app on my main machine (LB) which has only Apache Server installed the app works fine but it doesn't load the external folder, how do I configure it to load it? Mount in httpd.conf or what? Please help.

**Architecture of load balancing server**

[image: Architecture of load balancing server]

Answer (score 0):

Using Alias did the job. In my case:

```
Alias /resources C:/path/to/resources

<Directory "C:/path/to/resources">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```